# EventHub and Receive

Tags: python-3.x, azure-eventhub

All,

I modified the sample Receive **python** script for **Azure EventHub** a bit but when I run it goes into a loop fetching the same events over and over. I'm not sending any events to the eventhub since I want to read what is there and I dont see a while loop here so how is this happening and how do I stop after it reads all the events currently in the EventHub?

Thanks
grajee

```
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/eventhub-readme?view=azure-python#consume-events-from-an-event-hub
import logging
from azure.eventhub import EventHubConsumerClient

connection_str = 'Endpoint=sb://testhubns01.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=getevents;SharedAccessKey=testtestest='
consumer_group = '$Default'
eventhub_name = 'testpart'
client = EventHubConsumerClient.from_connection_string(connection_str, consumer_group, eventhub_name=eventhub_name)

logger = logging.getLogger("azure.eventhub")
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

def on_event(partition_context, event):
    logger.info("Received event from partition: \"{}\"   :  \"{}\"" .format(partition_context.partition_id,event.body_as_str()))
    partition_context.update_checkpoint(event)

with client:
    client.receive(
        on_event=on_event,
        starting_position="-1",  # "-1" is from the beginning of the partition.
    )
    # receive events from specified partition:
    # client.receive(on_event=on_event, partition_id='0')

client.close()
```

Comment: Currently, your sample is not storing a "checkpoint" (last read event). As a result, you are receiving all events in your eventhub, rather than the events that have not been read yet. In order to persist checkpoints, you need to use the CheckpointStoreBlob. Quickstart here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub/samples/sync_samples/recv_with_checkpoint_store.py
Sample here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub/samples/sync_samples/recv_with_checkpoint_store.py

Comment: Does this mean that receive will fetch all and then go on a loop all over?

Comment: no, as long as you are using the same CheckpointStore, it will keep track of the last received event and continue to receive where it left off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below piece of code from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/eventhub-readme?view=azure-python#consume-events-and-save-checkpoints-using-a-checkpoint-store) makes it more clear .

```
import asyncio

from azure.eventhub.aio import EventHubConsumerClient
from azure.eventhub.extensions.checkpointstoreblobaio import BlobCheckpointStore

connection_str = '<< CONNECTION STRING FOR THE EVENT HUBS NAMESPACE >>'
consumer_group = '<< CONSUMER GROUP >>'
eventhub_name = '<< NAME OF THE EVENT HUB >>'
storage_connection_str = '<< CONNECTION STRING FOR THE STORAGE >>'
container_name = '<<NAME OF THE BLOB CONTAINER>>'

async def on_event(partition_context, event):
    # do something
    await partition_context.update_checkpoint(event)  # Or update_checkpoint every N events for better performance.

async def receive(client):
    await client.receive(
        on_event=on_event,
        starting_position="-1",  # "-1" is from the beginning of the partition.
    )

async def main():
    checkpoint_store = BlobCheckpointStore.from_connection_string(storage_connection_str, container_name)
    client = EventHubConsumerClient.from_connection_string(
        connection_str,
        consumer_group,
        eventhub_name=eventhub_name,
        **checkpoint_store=checkpoint_store,  # For load balancing and checkpoint. Leave None for no load balancing**
    )
    async with client:
        await receive(client)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```